# Why is my stored procedure that returns only a single integer return code running out of heap space?

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm refactoring some code that was previously java 5 & JDBC calls to using java 8 & Spring 4. For the stored procedure calls I created classes that extend org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure. The constructor sets up the parameters, and the execute puts the 2 parameters on an input map and calls execute on the super class with the input parameter map.

The stored procedure runs for awhile, but the only thing it returns is a single number return code. It is calling other stored procs to move data around the database. But it seems like my call is leaking memory because if I run against a big enough data set it starts throwing `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java heap space`.

The kicker is there was no changes to the stored proc & the old code could handle calling the stored proc with the same amount of data without running out of memory. I'm guessing there's something I'm missing or setting in the StoredProcedure class that's causing the issue but I'm not sure what since I'm still pretty new to the framework.

The stored procedure class:

```
public class Extract extends StoredProcedure {
    private static final String PARAM_1 = "@PARAM_1";
    private static final String PARAM_2 = "@PARAM_2";

    public Extract(DataSource dataSource, String sprocName) {
        super(dataSource, sprocName);
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(Constants.STORED_PROC_RETURN_CODE, Types.VARCHAR, null,
            new SqlReturnType() {
                public Object getTypeValue(CallableStatement cs, int paramIndex, int sqlType, String typeName)
                        throws SQLException {
                    final Integer retCode = cs.getInt(paramIndex);
                    return retCode;
                }
            }));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(PARAM_1, Types.NUMERIC));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(PARAM_2, Types.NUMERIC));
        setFunction(true);
        compile();
    }

    public Map<String, Object> execute(Util util, CustomLogger logger)     {
        String params = util.EXTRACT_PARAMS;
        String arr[] = params.split(",");
        logger.writeLine("Extract SP Params are " + arr[0] + ":" + arr[1]);
        int firstParam = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        int secondParam = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
        Map<String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        inputs.put(PARAM_1, firstParam);
        inputs.put(PARAM_2, secondParam);
        return super.execute(inputs);
    }
}
```

The code calling the stored proc:

```
public int executeExtractSP() throws Exception {
      int returnCode = -1;
      try {
            Extract extractSP = new Extract(getDataSource(), util.EXTRACT_SP);
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            returnCode = (Integer) extractSP.execute(util, customLogger).get(Constants.STORED_PROC_RETURN_CODE);
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - t1;
            customLogger.writeLine("Extract procedure finished running in " + t2 + " milliseconds, return code is " + returnCode);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
                  throw ex;
      }
      return returnCode;
}
```

the old code calling the stored proc before refactor:

```
callStm = con.prepareCall(util.EXTRACT_SP);
callStm.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
callStm.setInt(2, firstParam);
callStm.setInt(3, secondParam);
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
boolean flag = callStm.execute();
long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - t1;
returnCode = callStm.getInt(1);
logger.writeLine("Extract procedure finished running in " + t2 + " milliseconds, return code is " + returnCode);
```

And the stack trace I'm getting with the memory error:

```
Thu Dec 17 20:48:56 2015: Extract SP Params are 1:2
Thu Dec 17 21:05:16 2015: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:469)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.extractReturnedResults(JdbcTemplate.java:1193)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1141)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1130)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1078)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1130)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.execute(StoredProcedure.java:142)
        at com.company.job.storedprocs.Extract.execute(Extract.java:49)
        at com.company.job.utils.DBUtil.executeExtractSP(DBUtil.java:456)
        at com.company.job.extract.JobExtract.processExtract(JobExtract.java:376)
        at com.company.job.Process.main(Process.java:60)
Thu Dec 17 21:05:16 2015: Exiting with code of 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the map getting pulled out of the execute line in the Extract class that extends StoredProcedure showed a map with over 30000 entries, including all of the messages from the stored procedure & an update-count entry for every update made by the stored proc called & the secondary stored procs the initial one called.

The method I needed to add was before calling the execute method, skip undeclared results. This reduced the map to just 1 entry, the return code number I was looking for.

```
super.getJdbcTemplate().setSkipUndeclaredResults(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL type of the parameter is varchar. I think this should be a Types.INTEGER.

Also, you are using a SqlReturnType to convert it to an Integer.  I don't think this is necessary.

Comment: Thanks John. I made those changes to simplify the out parameter since the conversion was unnecessary, but it didn't resolve the memory issue. There was another change that resolve the issue I'll post in a separate comment.